# sed pattern matching between lines

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I am trying to write a sed script to only output the lines of a file if the line has the /pattern/ and is between line x and line y. I have the following:

```
./select.sed -n test.txt
```

select.sed:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
/pattern/p
```

If my text.file is the the following:

```
1 line 1
2 pattern
3 line 3
4 pattern
5 line 5
```

The desired output would be

```
2 pattern

4 pattern
```

How would I set a range for lines 2-4 and only print values with "pattern"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -n 'x,y{/regexp/p}' file
```

- `-n` means do not print pattern space automatically.
- `x,y` means operate only on lines between `x`. and `y`. line.
- `/regexp/p` means print pattern space if `regexp` matches against pattern space.

Comment: I tried x,y/patten/p. Didnt know i need brackets. Thanks for the help